# Selenium 2.41 RemoteWebDriver: Not able to register node to hub

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I have Hub-Node setup for selenium remotewebdriver. I run following commands on windows-7 command prompt:

```
Hub: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub
Node: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,version=10,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10, -browser  browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10, -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10, -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\exe\IEDriverServer32.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\exe\chromedriver.exe" -port 5559
```

This runs well on selenium jar 2.32. Now I am migrating to 2.41. But when I run above commands (*by replacing 2.32 to 2.41*) node do not connect to hub. It just waits at following message:

```
INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Any help or pointer is appreciated. Am I missing something?

OS: Windows 7
Browser: IE 10, Chrome
Selenium: 2.41

```
Grid Console v.2.41.0
Help
DefaultRemoteProxy (version : 2.41.0)
id : http://10.253.66.243:5559, OS : WINDOWS
BrowsersConfiguration
port:5559
servlets:[]
host:10.253.66.243
cleanUpCycle:5000
browserTimeout:0
hubHost:localhost
registerCycle:5000
hub:http://localhost:4444/grid/register
capabilityMatcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
newSessionWaitTimeout:-1
url:http://10.253.66.243:5559
remoteHost:http://10.253.66.243:5559
prioritizer:null
Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\D\shared\SAFAL Web Version\code\IEDriverServer32.exe:
register:true
Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\D\shared\SAFAL Web Version\code\chromedriver.exe:
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true
nodePolling:5000
proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy
browser:browserName=iexplore,version=10,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10,
maxSession:5
role:node
jettyMaxThreads:-1
hubPort:4444
timeout:300000
Config for the hub :
host : null
port : 4444
cleanUpCycle : 5000
timeout : 300000
browserTimeout : 0
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
grid1Mapping : {}
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
prioritizer : null
servlets : 

all params :

browserTimeout : 0
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
cleanUpCycle : 5000
host : null
jettyMaxThreads : -1
maxSession : 5
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
nodePolling : 5000
port : 4444
prioritizer : null
role : hub
servlets : []
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
timeout : 300000

Config details :
hub launched with :-role hub 
the final configuration comes from :
the default :
host : null
port : 4444
cleanUpCycle : 5000
timeout : 300000
browserTimeout : 0
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
grid1Mapping : {}
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
prioritizer : null
servlets : 

all params :

browserTimeout : 0
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
cleanUpCycle : 5000
host : null
jettyMaxThreads : -1
maxSession : 5
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
nodePolling : 5000
port : 4444
prioritizer : null
servlets : []
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
timeout : 300000

updated with grid1 config :No grid1 file specified. To specify one, use -grid1Yml XXX.yml where XXX.yml is a grid1 config file

updated with grid2 config : No hub config file specified. To specify one, use -hubConfig XXX.json where XXX.json is a hub config file

updated with params :
host : null
port : 4444
cleanUpCycle : 5000
timeout : 300000
browserTimeout : 0
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
grid1Mapping : {}
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
prioritizer : null
servlets : 

all params :

browserTimeout : 0
capabilityMatcher : org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher
cleanUpCycle : 5000
host : null
jettyMaxThreads : -1
maxSession : 5
newSessionWaitTimeout : -1
nodePolling : 5000
port : 4444
prioritizer : null
role : hub
servlets : []
throwOnCapabilityNotPresent : true
timeout : 300000
```

Comment: Are you sure? Look at the console of the grid, is it connected?

Comment: at console it is just waiting: 'INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://localhost:4444/grid/register'

Comment: The **grid console**. `http://localhost:4444/grid/console`

Comment: Updated problem statement with grid console output.

Comment: Any pointers on this issue? I am still struggling to get the solution.

Comment: I guess there is some issue from selenium side itself. I have raised a bug on selenium web site. Waiting for their analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Hub:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub -timeout 30 -browserTimeout 60
```

Node:

```
http://localhost:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="pathToIEDriver\IEDriverServer.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="pathToChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=latest,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=25,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```

Comment: Tried with 2.42.2. But still issue persists. :(

Comment: switched back to older selenium version 2.32.